# Print all values of a given key of dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks something like this:

```
list =[{"id": 1, "status": "new", "date_created": "09/13/2013"}, {"id": 2, "status": "pending", "date_created": "09/11/2013"}, {"id": 3, "status": "closed", "date_created": "09/10/2013"}]
```

What i want to do is be able to print all of the values in this list of dictionaries that relate to "id" If it was just 1 dictionary i know i could do like:

```
print list["id"]
```

If it was just one dictionary, but how do i do this for a list of dictionaries? I tried:

```
for i in list:
    print i['id']
```

but i get an error that says

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Can someone give me a hand? Thanks!

Comment: The for loop works fine for me.  You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, since that reassigns the built in `list` constructor function, but at least in my installation that's not a fatal error.  You probably have something else wrong that you're not showing.

Comment: Your code works for me. o_O What version of python are you using

Comment: Your code works for me too, can you check it one more time ?

Comment: Something in the list is not a dictionary, but a string - try printing `i` and you'll find what's causing the error. @PeterDeGlopper - please stop using this totally wrong terminology. Just declaring a variable with a name like `list` or `dict` won't _reassign_ or _overwrite_ any built-ins; in fact to do that you'd have to be pretty explicit about it and import the `__builtin__` module and change its attributes. All that happens when calling a variable `list` is that it _shadows_ the built-in, meaning you can't access the list constructor by using `list()` in the scope of your variable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, your variable was reassigned a string value, instead of being a list of dictionaries.

```
>>> "foo"['id']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Otherwise, your code would work.

```
>>> list=[{'id': 3}, {'id': 5}]
>>> for i in list:
...   print i['id']
...
3
5
```

but the advice about not using `list` as a name still stands.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the below in Python shell and it works:

```
In [1]: mylist =[{"id": 1, "status": "new", "date_created": "09/13/2013"}, {"id": 2, "status": "pending", "date_created": "09/11/2013"}, {"id": 3, "status": "closed", "date_created": "09/10/2013"}]

In [2]: for item in mylist:
   ...:     print item
   ...: 
{'status': 'new', 'date_created': '09/13/2013', 'id': 1}
{'status': 'pending', 'date_created': '09/11/2013', 'id': 2}
{'status': 'closed', 'date_created': '09/10/2013', 'id': 3}

In [3]: for item in mylist:
    print item['id']
   ...: 
1
2
3
```

Never use reserved words or names that refer to built-in types (as in the case of `list`) as a name for your variables.

Comment: Downvote. `list` isn't a _reserved word_, it is just the name for the built-in list type. And while using it as a variable name shadows this builtin in the scope of the variable, that's usually not a problem at all. The real problem with using `list` as a variable name is that it is extremely nondescriptive (it's a list, but what does it contain?) - a speaking variable name should be preferred as it tells the reader the purpose of the variable, not just its data type.

Comment: @l4mpi OK, you're right, thanks. I've updated my answer to reflect your point. In this case I used `mylist` as it was the simplest way to substitute `list` as the variable's name OP was using.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend Python's list comprehensions:

```
print [li["id"] for li in list]
```